# How to retrieve an item ID from an item from JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, asp.net-web-api

I'm using a web service that returns food menu items to me from a variety of restaurants. Once a user enters a restaurant name and clicks the "search" button, the user is directed to a table view populated with menu items.

Here is the code that retrieves the data from the service (probably irrelevant for now, but could come in use for your guys' answers)
:

```
  NSString *userString = [userEnteredText text];
    NSString *correctedString = [userString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];

    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.nutritionix.com/v1_1/search/%@?results=0%%3A20&cal_min=0&cal_max=50000&fields=item_name%%2Cbrand_name%%2Citem_id%%2Cbrand_id&appId=MY_APP_ID&appKey=MY_APP_KEY", correctedString];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad
                                            timeoutInterval:30];

    NSData *urlData;
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *error;


    urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest
                                    returningResponse:&response
                                                error:&error];

    NSMutableDictionary *foodDataArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:urlData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    NSMutableDictionary *items = [foodDataArray objectForKey:@"hits"];

    NSMutableArray *fields = [items valueForKey:@"fields"];

    itemNamesArray = [fields valueForKey:@"item_name"];
```

Just like how I retrieved "item_name", I can retrieve an array of "item_id".

When the user clicks on a menu item, I want to retrieve that item's id and plug it into the service to retrieve the nutritional facts of that menu item.

I tried the following:

This is in my prepareForSegue method where "MVC" is my destination View Controller.

```
  theItemIDArray = [fields valueForKey:@"item_id"];
  [MVC setItemIDArray:theItemIDArray];
```

Then in my MVC.m I have this code:

```
-(void)setItemIDArray:(NSMutableArray *)b
{
theitemIDArray = b;
}
```

As you can see, I'm passing my array of itemID's from my original view controller to my destination view controller.

Here comes the part where I have to pass in an item ID in order to get that item's nutritional info.

In my prepareForSegue on my destination view controller, I attempt to pass in the array like so:

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.nutritionix.com/v1_1/item?id=%@&appId=MY_APP_ID&appKey=MY_APP_KEY", theitemIDArray];
```

However, this urlString requires me to pass in an NSString, not an NSMutableArray.

So my question is: How can I retrieve the itemID of the cell I clicked on and plug in that ID to return the nutritional info?

Sorry for the lengthy format and abundance of code, but I've been at this issue for hours with no glimpse of success.

Answer (score 0):

Is the "item_id" supposed to be multiple objects? Or does it just happen to come as an array of one item? I will assume that is an array of one item for this answer, given what I know about the nutritionix api.
What you will want to do is grab the first item in that array, so you will want grab it by calling [theitemIDArray firstObject]:

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.nutritionix.com/v1_1/item?id=%@&appId=MY_APP_ID&appKey=MY_APP_KEY", [theitemIDArray firstObject]];
```

Another thing to consider is storing the itemID as a string instead of an array:

```
theItemIDArray = [fields valueForKey:@"item_id"];
[MVC setItemID:[theItemIDArray firstObject]];
```

Then you can just use that itemID when making the call to the nutritional api for that item

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you have something like a table for the user to choose items from? And when they tap a row, you need the item ID for that row?

You already store the item name in the row, or access the name in the row configuration method. You should be able to find the row's item ID in the same manner. Either store it in the row or use the Ross's indexPath.row to index into the itemID array.